# Jquery UI - display same dialog twice on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm needing to display the same dialog twice on one page, at the same time, in different places.

How would I go about this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .clone() on the original element you used to create the dialog. Then use .dialog() on the element and it's clone.

```
var jElem = $('#someelem');
var jClone = jElem.clone();
$('body').append(jClone);
jElem .dialog({...});
jClone.dialog({...});
```